# jQuery smooth scrolling not working with SSL URL

Tags: jquery, ssl, https

Hope someone has a simple solution to my problem. I developed a website and tested it on a local webserver (wamp) on my desktop.
Smooth scrolling to id's on the website works perfectly. But after uploading to the actual server where the website has to be placed it doesn't work anymore. This server uses a SSL certificate (https://).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Extra info: I call the https jquery libraries in the head section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What makes you think it is to do with SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Your third js file would get blocked as it is not from a https source url. If your smooth scrolling requires jQuery 1.7 it won't work.

You can check for js errors in your web inspector.

To fix change:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your url is hosted on an secure server and since some urls are insecure, the browser would not read it.

Try to read all javascript files from a secure server (add https).